# How to return the 2nd data variable of an $.ajax() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my ajax function. How do I console.log the first data variable? The below code doesn't work:

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'text': $('.comment_text').serialize(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
        success: function() {
            console.log(text) 
        }
    })
})
```

However when I do this:

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data:
            $('.comment_text').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
})
```

it works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: what is not working? because you have serialize one in the working one then you have to change the code accordingly for the first one as you are sending an object back to server with two different keys.

Comment: Paste your `HTML` also.

Comment: try console.log(data.text)

Comment: The first success callback should be like this "success: function(data) { console.log(data.text); }"

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
success: function() {
    console.log(text) 
}
```

`text` doesn't exist in this context.

`this.data.text` would work because you're inside a method of your object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'text': $('.comment_text').serialize(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
        },
    success: function() {
        console.log(this.data.text);
        // everything from the object is accessible with this here (i.e. type and data fields)
    }
})
```

Comment: How else do you log data variables?

Comment: Still has the same outcome. It console.logs: `text=comment_text%3Dthetextentered&csrfmiddlewaretoken=%‌​7B%7B+csrf_token+%7D‌​%7D`

Comment: That's because of what `text` is - i.e. a serialized jquery string. For the value you'd need something else like $('.comment_text').val() but this was not the question you posted imho

Answer (score 1):

try to get the data you want to send to an external variable so you will have access to its properties inside the ajax success callback function.

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var _data = {
        'text': $('.comment_text').serialize(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: _data,
        success: function() {
            console.log(_data.text) 
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: How this is different as per OP's code? This as same as OP and this also does not solves the issue.

Comment: then you question is not clear at all. you want to get the value of the data you send or receive?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($('.comment_text').val())
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use serialize() over .val()?

Comment: No, you can check it's getting value over or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is working because it's logging the parameter `data`of the success callback function, aka the response from the server.

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var dataToSend = {
        text: $('.comment_text').serialize(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataToSend,
        success: function() {
            console.log(dataToSend.text) 
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Same outcome. It console.logs: `text=comment_text%3Dsomethingsomething&csrfmiddlewaretoken=%7B%7B+csrf_token+%7D%7D`

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to achive.. you want to read the response from the server? Or something from the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** 
If you just want to access the same text what you are sending in ajax data hit then you have to initialize it first. Because text is not any variable here so far so it will give undefined. You can do it like:

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
var requestData = {
    'text': $('.comment_text').serialize(),
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
};
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: requestData ,
    success: function() {
        console.log(requestData.text) 
    }
})
```

})

**Case 2:** If you are trying to access the text from ajax response then you have to pass the same parameter in success function.

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'text': $('.comment_text').serialize(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
        },
    success: function(text) {
        console.log(text) 
    }
})
```

})

Comment: Same outcome for both cases, It console.logs: `text=comment_text%3Dsomethingsomething&csrfmiddlewaretoken=%‌​7B%7B+csrf_token+%7D‌​%7D`

Comment: And what is the expected outcome ??

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to serialize and want some data to be sent along the way.

Here is what I do:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);
formData.append('custom_key', 'CUSTOM VALUE');
...
```

Then in AJAX data:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : formData,
    ...
});
```

Now in the backend code you can find your form fields as well as your custom key value.

Hope this helps.